# Any way to get local machine IP address without internet connection and not using webRTC

Tags: javascript, angular

i am trying to get local machine's ip address when machine is not connected to internet using WebRTC which is not working any other way for that

Comment: Without an internet connection you wouldn't have a routable public IP. So which IP address you're targetting?

Comment: @Nuhman I am looking for local machine ip not public ip

Comment: Why webRTC is not working? Right now `RTCPeerConnection` seems to be the only way.

Comment: i have situation whre i need to disconnect from LAN.. so i am not getting the IP

Comment: @Nuhman  you can have a local IP, if the machine is connected to a LAN. It might even have multiple IPs if it's connected to multiple networks (e.g., plugged in *and* wireless). Whether or not you have access to the internet doesn't make a difference in the ability to join a network.

Comment: @VLAZ yes there can be local private IPs. That's why I specifically asked for "public IP".